# QT and Boost : Cannot find -llibboost_filesystem

Tags: windows, qt, boost, qt-creator

I work with (and I cannot an other version of Qt) :

- QT Creator 2.4.1 and QT 4.8.4 (with Mingw compiler)
- boost 1.52

To build boost :

- I first added "C:/Qt/qtcreator-2.4.1/mingw/bin" to my PATH variable
- then opened a command prompt
- went to "C:/boost_1_52"
- typed "bootstrap.bat mingw"
- and then "b2 toolset=gcc build-type=complete stage" (this took a long time (about 2h))

I would like to use QT creator with the boost library but I come up against difficulties.
My project is very simple, it's only basic QT code :

```
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv) 
return a.exec()
```

I just added some includes :

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp> 
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
```

In my .pro file I have added :

```
DEFINES += BOOST_ALL_USE_LIB

INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_52
LIBS += -LC:/boost_1_52/stage/lib \
-lboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_52 \
-lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1-52 \
-lboost_timer-mgw48-mt-1_52

#"libboost_system..." needs this library
LIBS += -LC:/windows_sdk/lib \
-lWS2_32
```

When I build my projects I have two kinds of 'undefined reference to' :

- some with 'thread' in it like :

  ```
  undefined reference to `boost::thread::thread()'
  undefined reference to `boost::thread::joinable() const'
  ```
- some that looks like :

  ```
  undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
  undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
  ```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved !

Some weeks ago, I installed strawberry pearl, which comes with MinGW 4.8.1
The MinGW that comes with Qt Creator is 4.4.0

So, in my environement variable `PATH`, I had "C:\Strawberry\c\bin" AND "C:\Qt\Qt creator\mingw\bin"

When I built boost, it must have used the latest version of MinGW it could find, which is the one that comes with Strawberry.

That's what was causing all my problems, I rebuilt boost with the MinGW from Qt creator and everything worked !

I did not pay enough attention to the "mg48" in my librairies' name

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
LIBS += "-LC:/boost_1_57_0/libs/" \
```

Comment: I forgot to update my question but I solved some errors.
In the end, I do not need "libboost_filesyste..." so I removed the part about it.

"libboost_system..." needs "WS2_32" from windows SDK so I linked it and the errors about "WSAStartup", "WSACleanup"... disappeared.

I still have two types of undefined reference to :
- some with 'thread' in it like "imp__ZN5boost6thread4joinEv"
- some that look like "boost::system::generic_category()"

I added the "libbost_thread..." library but that does not help.

I'll update my question